# Issue in connecting to MS Access(accdb) database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to connect to MS Access database(*.accdb) using OdbcConnection class in my C# application.

Below is the code that I tried:

```
string connetionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Temp\\Database4.accdb";

OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);

try
{                   
    myConnection.Open();

    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

But it gets the below exception on the myConnection.Open() call.

> "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified"

But the above code is working for .mdb file if I use the connection string like below:

```
string connetionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\Temp\\Database4.mdb";
```

But my requirement is to connect to a .accdb file.

Any idea of what is wrong with my code or connection string format?

Comment: I have edited the question please move it off hold

Comment: The Microsoft ODBC driver that supports accdb files is called _Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)_, and requires the Access Database Engine to be installed (32-bits variant if your program is 32-bits, 64-bits if your program is 64-bits). Adjust your program with that info. You have my reopen vote btw.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following the code:

```
    const string connetionString = @"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Temp\Database4.accdb";
    OdbcConnection myConnection = new OdbcConnection(connetionString);
    myConnection.Open();
    myConnection.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

But it will work only on x86 configuration and not with x64 configuration. For x64 configuration, we have to go for OleDbConnection class.

Thank you all..